# GitLab Pipeline: Access external Files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

I got a pipeline up and working.
My supervisor gave me access to a VM, on which I installed gitlab-runner and all needed dependencies (I'm using the shell mode).

The build task runs without problems, but I also want to create some tests.
The Problem is, that the program input are files, which contents are secret and therefore are not included in the repository.

I stored the files on the VM (e.g. in `/path/to/file.txt`). But when I pass the (absolute) path to the file in the test job, in the script section:

```yaml
variables:
  FILE: "/path/to/file.txt"
...
test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./build/my_program $FILE
```

then I get the (it's a c++ program) (test-job)pipeline error output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  ERROR: File /path/to/file.txt not found
bash: line 145: 52372 Aborted                 ./build/my_program $FILE
```

How can I pass local files, which are stored on the machine and not in the repository to a job?
Or is there even a best practice on passing local/ secret files to a test?